# update a certain column with a set value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, postgresql, methods

I have a set of customers that have credits within my store, i am trying to find their current balance, then adjust it with a new balance, but when doing so i keep getting Amount Invalid but I cannot for the live of work out why this is

CONTROLLER

```
class Admin::UserDatas::StoreCreditsController < Admin::UserDatas::BaseController
  helper_method :customer
  def show
    @store_credit = customer.store_credit
  end

  def edit
    form_info
  end

  def update
    result = Braintree::Transaction.sale(
        :amount => :amount_added,
        :customer_id => customer.customer_cim_id,
        :options => {
            :submit_for_settlement => true
        }
    )
    if result.success?
      p 'Transaction Successful'
      customer.store_credit.add_credit(:amount_added)
      redirect_to admin_user_datas_user_store_credits_url(customer), :notice => "Successfully updated store credit."
    else
      result.errors.each do |error|
        puts error.message
        customer.errors.add(:base, error.message)
        form_info
        render :edit, :notice => error.message
      end
    end
  end

  private
  def form_info

  end

  def customer
    @customer ||= User.includes(:store_credit).find(params[:user_id])
  end

  def amount_added
    params[:amount_to_add].to_f
  end

end
```

METHODS

```
def remove_credit(amount_to_remove)
    credit_amount = "#{self.amount} - #{amount_to_remove.to_f.round(2)}"
    self.update(amount: credit_amount)
  end

  def add_credit(amount_to_add)
    credit_amount = "#{self.amount} + #{amount_to_add.to_f.round(2)}"
    self.update(amount: credit_amount)
  end
```

FORM PARTIAL

```
%ul.admin-standard_form.prepend-8{:id => ""}
  %li.field
    = label :amount_to_add, 'Amount to Add'
    = text_field_tag :amount_to_add
```

EDIT TEMPLATE

```
%h3
  Change #{customer.name} Store Credit
%ul
  %li
    %label Current Amount:
    = number_to_currency customer.store_credit_amount
= form_for customer, :url => admin_user_datas_user_store_credits_path( customer ) do |f|
  = render :partial => 'form', :locals => {:f => f}
  .actions= f.submit 'Update' , :class => 'button'
```

ERRORS

```
Started PATCH "/en/admin/user_datas/users/1/store_credits" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-06-24 21:56:08 +1000
Processing by Admin::UserDatas::StoreCreditsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "amount_to_add"=>"200", "commit"=>"Update", "locale"=>"en", "user_id"=>"1"}
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."remember_token" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["remember_token", "cfe807bd1caa3763df52dcb18de8c9d4f350b933"]]
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  StoreCredit Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "store_credits".* FROM "store_credits" WHERE "store_credits"."user_id" IN (1)
I, [2016-06-24T21:56:09.418606 #8775]  INFO -- : [Braintree] [24/Jun/2016 11:56:09 UTC] POST /merchants/XXXX/transactions 422
Amount is an invalid format.
  Rendered admin/user_datas/store_credits/_form.html.haml (0.7ms)
  Rendered admin/user_datas/store_credits/edit.html.haml within layouts/superman (4.0ms)
  Rendered shared/_meta_data.html.haml (4.6ms)
  Rendered admin/shared/_side_menu.html.haml (2.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 1085ms (Views: 47.2ms | ActiveRecord: 1.3ms)
```

MORE ERRORS

```
Started PATCH "/en/admin/user_datas/users/1/store_credits" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-06-24 22:20:46 +1000
Processing by Admin::UserDatas::StoreCreditsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "amount_to_add"=>"20", "commit"=>"Update", "locale"=>"en", "user_id"=>"1"}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."remember_token" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["remember_token", "cfe807bd1caa3763df52dcb18de8c9d4f350b933"]]
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  StoreCredit Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "store_credits".* FROM "store_credits" WHERE "store_credits"."user_id" IN (1)
I, [2016-06-24T22:20:50.681897 #8775]  INFO -- : [Braintree] [24/Jun/2016 12:20:50 UTC] POST /merchants/mbmb637xwpzgxbrd/transactions 201
"Transaction Successful"
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
Redirected to http://0.0.0.0:3000/en
Completed 302 Found in 3848ms (ActiveRecord: 1.6ms)
```

Comment: Can you copy the Error Logs here. It will narrow down the exact error you are facing

Comment: added logs @QaisarNadeem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your `update` action

You are passing wrong value to `amount` field in `Braintree::Transaction` you are passing `:amount_added` (which is a symbol) instead of actual amount which is `params[:amount_to_add]` that's why this error occurs. It says Invalid amount type. so Update your action to

```
def update
    result = Braintree::Transaction.sale(
        :amount => params[:amount_to_add].to_f,
        :customer_id => customer.customer_cim_id,
        :options => {
            :submit_for_settlement => true
        }
    )
    if result.success?
      p 'Transaction Successful'
      customer.store_credit.add_credit(params[:amount_to_add].to_f)
      redirect_to admin_user_datas_user_store_credits_url(customer), :notice => "Successfully updated store credit."
    else
      result.errors.each do |error|
        puts error.message
        customer.errors.add(:base, error.message)
        form_info
        render :edit, :notice => error.message
      end
    end
  end
```

P.S same is the case for `customer.store_credit.add_credit(:amount_added)` 
change it to `customer.store_credit.add_credit params[:amount_to_add]`

**Update**

Change `add_credit` method to

```
  def remove_credit(amount_to_remove)
    credit_amount = self.amount - amount_to_remove.to_f.round(2)
    self.update(amount: credit_amount)
  end
```

Comment: this isn't making it a float though

Comment: that has fixed one error, but it still won't save to the db

Comment: that has introduce a new error of not being able to convert to_f

Comment: actual it did fix it, i missed the params for the add credit

Comment: Oh got it, btw I wrote explicitly in the answer to pass correct params to add_credit . 
I am happy to help